# Monitor log file for a keyword then send an email notification

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I want to monitor a log that's continually generating, for a keyword to let me know if a component is down. Once the keyword is identified, I'd like to be notified via email to my personal gmail.

So far I've been able to accomplish the keyword monitoring and email notification separately but never together in a script. I've tried the following for monitoring:

```
tail -fn0 user | awk '/disconnect_tcp_conn/ { print | "echo server down" }'
```

And this to email:

```
mail -s "server down.... again" blahblah@gmail.com < /dev/null
```

I tried grep for monitoring but it seemed like awk worked best.. at least for how I used it. Just can't seem to get the syntax correct to make both work at the same time.

I've tried:

```
tail -fn0 user | awk '
                    /disconnect_tcp_conn/ { print | "echo server down") }
                    /disconnect_tcp_conn/ { system( "mail -s "server down.... again" blahblah@gmail.com < /dev/null ") }'
```

and also:

```
tail -fn0 user | awk '
                    /disconnect_tcp_conn/ { print | "echo server down") }
                    /disconnect_tcp_conn/ { cmd=mail -s "server down.... again3" blahblah@gmail.com < /dev/null ") }'
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple lines in an `{action}`, and you can escape the double quotes `\"` that you want to pass through `system()`:

```
tail -fn0 user | awk '/disconnect_tcp_conn/ { 
    system("mail -s \"server down... again\" blahblah@gmail.com </dev/null") 
    print "server down... again"
    exit
}'
```

Comment: cannot open `user' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining

Comment: The above were the results @vintnes

Comment: @Sceptersax use the full path to the file you're trying to read, or `cd` into the directory first

Comment: Ah. Should’ve thought of that @vintnes. I’ll try it in the morning at the office. Thanks

Comment: perfection. Thanks

Comment: And thanks for the tip. I now realize you can have multiple lines in an {action} and the \" escape to pass through system

Comment: the only problem i have with this is that now the operation continues to send emails with no end... I found the following code that ends the system command without ending the monitoring: '{if(!seen[$1]++)print $1}' but im having a hard time introducing it to the code above.

Comment: Just throw an `exit` in there. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can simply also be done as below :

```
tail -f /path/to/file | while read line
do case "$line" in
        *"server down"*) echo "$line" | mutt -s "Server Down" an_email@mail.com;
        ;;
   esac
done
```

Comment: This also seemed to work but when I substituted "an_email@email.com;" with my email i received: No recipients were specified. I'm sure with some minor adjustments on my part this would work but I am going to just use the awk command to make this happen. Thanks